# Is it possible to prevent a web browser from saving website credentials?

Tags: iis, browser, basic-authentication

I have a website protected by basic auth, so when someone hits it, they get a standard username/password box.  This website is accessed often from shared computers.

Is there any way to prevent the various "Remember my Credentials" functionality on browsers?  I would like to prevent any browser from saving this username/password in any client-side repository.

I realize this is purely a function of the browser, but is there any commonly-accepted HTTP header or any other method of asking a website not to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. I'm really sorry but even if you could do this how would you  stop an independent add-in from scraping web sites for username and password boxes and then storing that information.

Even if this were possible in code it could be easily circumvented by simply ignoring any directives you give. Thus rendering such headers pointless.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a longshot and that it would be purely at the browser's discretion, but I wondered if they all agreed to some protocol for this.

Comment: No I'm afraid not + 1 for decent question tho

Answer (score 0):

As stated before it is not possible to circumvent a browser feature it could easily save the credentials before it sent the `POST` thus stopping anything on the server from preventing it being cached.